# xgettext incorrectly infers 'c-format' in cpp files

Tags: internationalization, xgettext

I have a bunch of .cpp files which contain text including a literal percent sign. Those files don't use `printf` at all, they use `iostream` stuff:

```
std::cout <<  _( "50 % of 10 is 5" ) << std::endl;
```

However, strings containing `%` are still marked as `c-format` by `xgettext`:

```
#: test.cpp:5
#, c-format
msgid "50 % of 10 is 5"
msgstr ""
```

This template then gets processed by `msgmerge` and translated, and translation tools (e.g. Poedit) complains about such entries:

```
#: test.cpp:5
#, c-format
msgid "50 % of 10 is 5"
msgstr "50 % de 10 est 5"
```

> Format specification in 'msgid' and 'msgstr' does not match

Manually removing the `#, c-format` comments helps, but they come back after every merge. How can I force `xgettext` or `msgmerge` to drop those comments? I know I can just filter them out with `sed`, but is there a smarter way, which would keep such comments for strings coming from C files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `gettext` documentation talks about this exact same issue here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/c_002dformat-Flag.html

According to the docs, you should use this special comment before the lines:

```
xgettext:no-c-format
```